# GluonHQ - Bars in BarChart do not appear

Tags: ios, javafx, javafx-8, gluon, gluon-mobile

I am facing a strange issue when trying to present data in a barchart with Gluon in iOS. The same app works OK on desktop. On iOS everything behave the same except that the bars in the chart do not appear. Any ideas?

[image: BarChart in iPhone 7]
[image: BarChart on Desktop]

Comment: I tested a regular BarChart on iOS, it works fine for me. It looks like you are using custom CSS for your chart. Can you try with the default one?

Comment: @JoséPereda I found what the problem is.In the code, the BarChart is not in the scene and is added once the data are received and set. For some reason there seem to be a problem in iOS. Bars do not appear when chart data are loaded in the background without the Chart Node being the scene

Comment: @JoséPereda It works fine by having node in the scene and setting off/on the visibility. Don't understand why though